# Генерация размещений.Скорость генерации.

Tags: c, c++

Такое вот задание: нужно сгенерировать размещения с повторениями с n по k. Это будет n^k елементов. Если n=2,k=128, то время генерации будет, скажем так, немалое ) Извесно также , что стандартная программа не использует всю мощь процесора , а только нагружает его на 5-6 процентов. Так вот собственно и вопрос : как использовать-то всю мощь моего двухядерного процесора и в свою очередь уменьшить время генерации размещений ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если программа только и делает, что все время что-то считает, то будет нагружено полностью ОДНО ядро процессора. Чтобы полностью нагрузить оба ядра, надо делать два потока, между которыми разделить вычисления и как-то их синхронизировать. Это простейший пример параллельных вычислений.

Можно программировать потоки вручную, используя API операционной системы, можно использовать обертки типа Boost.Threads или потоки C++11. Можно применить какой-нибудь фреймворк. Особенно удобен для данной задачи OpenMP.

Comment: Только синхронизацией не слишком увлекайтесь. Весьма затратно. Просто алгоритм должен естественно распараллеливаться на независимые части (без пересечения по данным). 

Для posiх threads в Linux (остальные на практике не проверял) *некоторое* превышение их количества над аппаратными ресурсами (n CPU или 2 \* n CPU при core hyperthreading) несущественно замедляет программу.